# SKAdNetwork iOS 14 Google Ads

Tags: ios, firebase, ios14, google-ads-api, skadnetwork

Hoping this community can help. We have a mobile app on iOS only. So, we haven't implemented any IDFA libraries to track conversions via Google Ads and relied solely on the Vendor Identifier. However, we're seeing a significant drop in performance/conversion tracking within Google Ads compared to 2019 where we'd see thousands of installs.

Per Google Ads support recommendation, we updated the Firebase SDK with the SKAdNetwork automatically calling registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution, but still seeing no conversions registered in Google Ads. All integrations within Firebase are correct.

Without having to add in the IDFA libraries, is there any other recommendation you have? Adding a specific plist dictionary for Google Ads or additional API calls? I found one for AdMods but we don't do any in-app advertising so assuming that's not applicable to us.

Any assistance would help!

Thanks in advance.